# Add Background Image to .scss File in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I was trying to add a background image to a canvas (Zurb Foundation 5) but got an error when I did this:

```
# Located in this file: foundation_and_overrides.scss
$off-canvas-bg: #fff url(../assets/img/canvas-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
```

Error shown:

```
$color: (white url(../assets/img/canvas-bg.jpg) no-repeat) is not a color for `scale-color'
```

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: How do you use your variable then?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this snippet of code ..

```
@mixin background($imgpath,$position:0 0,$repeat: no-repeat) {
    background: {
        image: url($imgpath);
        position: $position;
        repeat: $repeat;
    }
}
.testing {
    @include background('/my/img/path.png');
}
```

This will then output:

```
.testing {
  background-image: url("/my/img/path.png");
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```